# crawl links of sitemap.xml through wget command

Tags: wget, web-crawler, sitemap.xml

I try to crawl all links of a sitemap.xml to re-cache a website. But the recursive option of wget does not work, I only get as respond:

> Remote file exists but does not contain any link -- not retrieving.

But for sure the sitemap.xml is full of "http://..." links.

I tried almost every option of wget but nothing worked for me:

```
wget -r --mirror http://mysite.com/sitemap.xml
```

Does anyone knows how to open all links inside of a website sitemap.xml?

Thanks,
Dominic

Answer (score 17):

It seems that `wget` can't parse XML. So, you'll have to extract the links manually. You could do something like this:

```
wget --quiet http://www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o "https?://[^<]+" | wget -i -
```

I learned this trick [here](http://www.wezm.net/technical/2009/05/spider-a-site-with-wget-using-sitemap-xml/).

Comment: How can I set each downloaded html filename to the title of the page? Right now everything is just index.html, index.html.1, index.html.2 etc

Comment: would like to see an elaboration on this that accounts for many children in the xml file structure...anyone? This is nice though! Thank you!

Comment: I have the sitemap in gz format, how should I visit urls from that.

Comment: Also I want get .amp pages, which are not list in sitemap. How do create amp url from these urls. My amp urls use .amp extension.

Answer (score 4):

While this question is older, google send me here.

I finally used xsltproc to parse the sitemap.xml:

sitemap-txt.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url">
            <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using it (in this case it is from a cache-prewarming-script, so the retrieved pages are not kept ("-o /dev/null"), only some statistics are printed ("-w ....")):

```
curl -sS http://example.com/sitemap.xml | xsltproc sitemap-txt.xsl - | xargs -n1 -r -P4 curl -sS -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\t%{time_total}\t%{url_effective}\n"
```

(Rewriting this to use wget instead of curl is left as an exercise for the reader ;-) )
What this does is:

1. Retrieve sitemap.xml
2. Parse sitemap, output url-list as texts (one url per line)
3. use xargs to call "curl" on each url, using 4 requests in parallel)

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Parsing the XML according to the sitemap schema is the only reliable solution.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Orient](https://orient.gg) has a free site crawler and sitemap generator as well.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -2):

You can use one of the sitemapping tools. Try [Slickplan](https://slickplan.com). It has the site crawler option and by using it you can import a structure of existing website and create a visual sitemap from it. Then you can export it to Slickplan XML format, which contains* not only links, but also SEO metadata, page titles (product names), and a bunch of other helpful data.